# How to read sensors from Xiaomi Gateway?

Tags: python-3.x, xiaomi

Command "miiocli cloud" returned:

```
Gateway (Устройство в сети ) ==
    Model: lumi.gateway.mgl03
    Token: XXXXXXXXXXXX
    IP: xxx.xx.xx
    DID: xxx
    Locale: ru
```

I try to read sensors connected to gateway, but command "miiocli device --ip xxx.xx.xx --token XXXXXXXXXXXX  --help" returned only:

```
Options:
  --ip TEXT     [required]
  --token TEXT  [required]
  --model TEXT
  --help        Show this message and exit.
 
Commands:
info             Get (and cache) miIO protocol information from the...
raw_command      Send a raw command to the device.
test_properties  Helper to test device properties.
```

Which command i need to send for reading sensors connected to gateway? I can't find :(

Full list of my devices:

```
Mi (WiFi) (Устройство не в сети ) ==
    Model: chuangmi.plug.hmi206
    Token: xxx
    IP: xxx (mac: xxx)
    DID: 458450446
    Locale: ru
 Gateway (Устройство в сети ) ==
    Model: lumi.gateway.mgl03
    Token: xxx
    IP: xxx (mac: xxx)
    DID: 463282479
    Locale: ru
 Robot vacuum (Устройство в сети ) ==
    Model: roborock.vacuum.a01
    Token: xxx
    IP: xxx (mac: xxx)
    DID: 317162333
    Locale: ru
 Temperature & humidity sensor (Устройство в сети ) ==
    Model: miaomiaoce.sensor_ht.t2
    Token: xxx
    IP:  (mac: xxx)
    DID: blt.6.18qkd3rq4sc00
    Locale: ru
 Orbi (Устройство в сети ) ==
    Model: miaomiaoce.sensor_ht.t2
    Token: xxx
    IP:  (mac: xxx)
    DID: blt.6.1cq3ahmb4sk00
    Locale: ru
```